# Explain this command: . ~/nvm/nvm.sh

Tags: linux, bash, nvm

I am by no means a novice user on Linux, but I just don't understand why one has to put . in front of this command:

```
. ~/nvm/nvm.sh
```

For those in the know, this is how to activate the nvm bash script (it allows for a virtual environment in the NodeJS universe). But if one does not put that starting period in front of the command, then things don't work out. As far as I know, the "." means current directory. Yet if I do this:

```
cd ~/nvm
nvm.sh
```

or this

```
~/nvm/nvm.sh
```

It will not work. Why? Why must one put "." and then a space before running this command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> . ~/nvm/nvm.sh
> ```

It asks the interpreter to interpret the script **in the current process**. In `bash` it's equivalent to:

```
source ~/nvm/nvm.sh
```

You need to execute a script in the current process if you want it to change the environment (variables, et al). You can view more details with `help .`

---

> ```
> ~/nvm/nvm.sh
> ```

This one actually runs the script **in a new bash process**. It cannot change the environment of the parent, for example it cannot export variables to the parent process.

Comment: To clarify `.` is an alias for [`source`](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html) in bash.

Comment: It is!!! Wow, that makes everything clear. Thank you so much, I don't know how I could not have known this.

Comment: One clarification - that last example (without `.` or `source`) does indeed run the script in a new `bash` (or whatever) process. However it *can* and *does* change the environment, just in a child process that then immediately exits, so the changes are lost. It cannot change the environment *in the parent process*.

Comment: @Orbling;  strictly speaking (I'm being picky) `.` is not an alias.  `.` is a builtin, just like `source`, which happens to execute exactly the same code as `source`.  The user cannot alter it which would be the case if it was an alias.  See `builtins/source.def` in the Bash source code.

Comment: @cdarke: Very true, it merely functions in the manner of an alias, a shortcut mnemonic.

Comment: @Orbling Interestingly, `.` is standard while `source` is not :-)

Comment: @cnicutar LOL, must be the other way round then.

Comment: @cnicular: `source` comes from csh.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` means run in the current shell so environment variables you've set or are set in the script are shared.  I would wager launching a new shell for the script puts it in an environment it cannot run in.